# Azure Cloud App ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: azure, marathon, azure-virtual-network, dcos, azure-container-service

I would like to deploy a container based app in azure container service, and followed this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-mesos-marathon-ui

Everything went well except that the public url is showing 
`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in browser.

When pinging the url, able to get the IP address but pings are showing as timed out.

I have verified agents LB with port 80 as allowed in the rules list.

How to access the application through public web ?

Comment: You should access nginx service with agent dns name like `http://shui78agents.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` not master dns name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When pinging the url, able to get the IP address but pings are showing
>   as timed out.

Azure disable ICMP package, so you could not ping Azure public IP address. You could use `telnet` or `tcping` to check whether your service is listening.

---

Do you bind port 80 of the container to port 80 of the DC/OS agent? If I don't do this, I get same error log with you. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-mesos-marathon-ui#deploy-a-docker-formatted-container).

[image]

[image]

Note: I test in my lab, if I did not do this, nginx service will listen on other port. I ssh to the agent VM.

```
root@dcos-agent-public-65818314000001:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
7e8091548413        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:4912->80/tcp   mesos-d7be0314-6be2-467b-8376-433a05033b17-S1.42edeac0-2aa3-4ecd-acaa-17d5f2f4ac19
```

The service is listening on port 4912 not 80.

If you do this step, I suggest you also could ssh to agent VM(same user name and private key) and execute `docker ps` .

Comment: Thanks it works now. I did configure the same 80 port as shown in the image. But the JSON configuration has hostport value to 0 when i observe, so i edited manually to 80 and worked fine. Thanks a lot