# Flask Docker image giving time-out error on Azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, flask

I am trying to run the [Flask mega-tutorial app](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xix-deployment-on-docker-containers) on Azure off Docker. The Dockerfile is as given [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.19/Dockerfile), first I tried EXPOSE 5000 (as mentioned in this Dockerfile ) but as that lead to ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT I then tried EXPOSE 80 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655402/azure-cloud-app-err-connection-timed-out):  but the error remained.

Both ports 5000 and 80 in the Dockerfile worked fine off local server. Also, in each case, for Azure the instanceView.state=="Running" but pinging the ip address does not return anything.

The Azure-Docker [helloWorld image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli) also runs fine and my Azure CLI commands are exactly the same as in this example except for changing the container registry name etc. Apart from CLI, I tried doing it on the Azure portal as well with same outcome.

Thanks

Comment: Any more question?

Answer (score 1):

When there is no issue with your image and it can work fine locally. It should be the port issue if you use the Azure Container Instance.

> Azure Container Instances does not currently support port mapping like
>   with regular docker configuration

It means that if you expose the port 5000 in the container and you should expose the same port in Azure Container Instance group. For more details, see [IPs may not be accessible due to mismatched ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#ips-may-not-be-accessible-due-to-mismatched-ports). Also, maybe it's better to use the port 80. Hope this will help you. If there is more question you can give me the message.

Test with your application gives in your GitHub. Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: I updated to port 80 in both shell script and Dockerfile and re-ran the application. My azure CLI commands and output of `az container create` are given [here](https://pastebin.com/ruY2vus9). 
Both container and Azure Container Instance Group expose port 80 but still getting the timed_out error. Thanks

Comment: What port does it listen in the hello world application?

Comment: port 80 mentioned in the helloWorld image link in the OP

Comment: You can take a look at the logs. There need more details.